# videojs demo no caption/subtitle buttons on ipad ios 8.1.3

Tags: html, video, captions

When I view the demo video on videojs.com on my ipad (ios 8.1.3) I can't see the caption button so I can't display the subtitles/captions?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of videoJs version. Try version 4.10.2 [link](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/tree/v4.10.2/dist/video-js)